# SVN Update not applying. Despite files marked as out of sync

Tags: svn

I recently created a project structure in SVN. Checked my project into the app folder, then made a number of edits. I was editing a version of the project that was not checked out however (my original project that I copy/pasted into the new SVN repo). I guess I just figured I could point it at the repo later and do an update and it would work. Another developer pulled the project, made some changes, and checked them in. In attempt to get my local project in sync; I pulled a new repo/project to my local with the SVN HEAD version, deleted all the files in the repo in which I had personally modified on my local, and replaced them with my edited files. I was hoping that if I just did an update from that point, SVN would attempt to merge my local changes with the HEAD in SVN.

When I update, nothing happens.

The files in my checked out project are showing red check marks, so SVN is aware that they are out of sync...

I tried to do Update to Revision with "fully recursive" on the root folder. Still nothing gets pulled.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean red marks in Windows Explorer? I've found they tend to be out of sync sometimes.

Comment: Yes but there is something to update. All the files marked red are in fact not in sync with the HEAD. However when I update the project or an individual file is just says "Update complete" and doesn't modify any files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should:

- revert all changes and update working copy to revision which you start to modify (not HEAD!)
- replace modified files in working copy
- update working copy to HEAD

In this case Subversion calculate difference made by colleague and apply them over your changes.

Comment: Thanks Sergey! Reverting the project to the original revision before my edits seemed to allow SVN to pick up the changes.